# Mongoose | Keep the same Population to all functions

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-populate

> I Have this schema for my Crop Model

```
var CropSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    zones: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'zone'
    }],
    ...
});
```

> This schema for my Zone Model

```
var ZoneSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    poor: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'condition'
    }],
    ...
});
```

> This schema for my Condition Model

```
var ConditionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    action_on_controls: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'control'
    }],
    ...
});
```

> And this schema for my Control Model

```
var ControlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    ...
});
```

> The way I am getting all the Crops in Node is this:

```
  public index(req: Request, res: Response) {
    return Crop.find().populate('zones').populate({
      path: 'zones',
      populate: [
        {
          path: 'poor', populate: [
            { path: 'action_on_controls' }]
        }
      ]
    }).exec()
      .then(respondWithResult(res, 200))
      .catch(handleError(res, 500));
  }
```

> The way I am getting an individual Crop is this:

```
  public show(req: Request, res: Response) {
    return Crop.findById(req.params.id).populate({
      path: 'zones',
      populate: [
        {
          path: 'poor', populate: [
            { path: 'action_on_controls' }]
        }
      ]
    }).exec()
      .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
      .then(respondWithResult(res, 200))
      .catch(handleError(res, 500));
  }
```

**As you can see, the part:**

> .populate({..})

**is repeated twice.**

**How can I keep the same populate configurations so I don't have to write/update the same thing all the time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the populate object as a variable and share it:

```
const zonePopulateObj = {
  path: 'zones',
  populate: [
    {
      path: 'poor', populate: [
        { path: 'action_on_controls' }]
    }
  ]
};
```

And then in your queries

```
return Crop.find().populate(zonePopulateObj).exec();

return Crop.findById(req.params.id).populate(zonePopulateObj).exec();
```

Or you could pull the query logic into a new function and share that

```
public index(req: Request, res: Response) {
    return findCrop()
      .then(respondWithResult(res, 200))
      .catch(handleError(res, 500));
  }


public show(req: Request, res: Response) {
    return findCrop(req.params.id)
      .then((array)=>array.length ? array[0] : {})
      .then(handleEntityNotFound(res)) // may need to update this function not sure how it checks for not found.
      .then(respondWithResult(res, 200))
      .catch(handleError(res, 500));
  }



  const findCrop = (id)=>{
      let queryObj = {};
      if(id){
          queryObj._id=id
      }
      return Crop.find(queryObj).populate({
        path: 'zones',
        populate: [
          {
            path: 'poor', populate: [
              { path: 'action_on_controls' }]
          }
        ]
      }).exec()
  }
```

Personally I prefer the first method.